# MVC 5 Routing Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5

Currently I have a Member controller which has 2 views, Index and Details, I would like to pass a string such as UserName to the view Details, which in turn displays the results of the query.

```
public ActionResult Details(string u)
{
    if (u == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    AspNetUser user = db.AspNetUsers.Find(u);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(user);
}
```

In the Index view I am using a link like so:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.UserName, "Details", new { u = item.UserName })
```

When I click a link such as:

```
http://localhost:11508/Member/Details?u=test7
```

I get the message:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you reach the controller?  I imagine `db.AspNetUsers.Find(u)` is returning null

Comment: Why are you using the controller name as `item.UserName` instead of `Member` as indicated in the URL?

Comment: I'm now getting a HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request when trying to use http://localhost:11508/Member/Details?u=test7. As for the controller name being `item.Username` that is incorrect, it is simply the text for the link. My link is displaying `test7` with a url of `/Member/Details?u=test7`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding the next line in RouteConfig.cs in RegisterRoutes method:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Details",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{u}",
        defaults: new { 
            controller = "Member", 
            action = "Details", 
            u = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: Just one more thing the url works, but is it possible to have the url return as `Member/Details/test5` instead of `/Member/Details?u=test5`?

Comment: To answer your question, it is possible and I will give you an example but it is not recommanded to use this approach. This will be in the register routes: 
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action.*}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Details" }
            );

And this will be your method:
public void Details()
        {
            string url = HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString();
            string u = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('s') + 1, 1);// Where u will be the userName
        }

Answer (score 0):

The method you are calling has the following signature:

```
protected internal virtual ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName, object model)
```

With the above method, C# thinks that the viewname is the username, which I assume is not correct. By using named parameters you can force a string as a model:

```
return View(viewName: "Details", model: item.UserName);
```

this way C# will use the correct method.

Answer (score 0):

Providing you use the default routes for this, you can change your controller method to use [Bind(Prefix="id")].

```
public ActionResult Details([Bind(Prefix="id")]string u)
{
    if (u == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    AspNetUser user = db.AspNetUsers.Find(u);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(user);
}
```

I think the method you use to find the user takes the userId though, and you send in the username. So that might be an issue as well!

Edit: example for finding the user by username

```
db.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(usr=>usr.UserName == u)
```

The [Bind] prefix is only for making the url follow the normal syntax.

Comment: I have modified my code as per your suggestion, I am now getting a HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request message.

Comment: OK, try only to change the query for the user then. AspNetUser user = db.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(usr=>usr.UserName == u); The [Bind] might not work if you dont have the default routes i guess.

Comment: I modified the query re your suggestion and added the route I simply added provided by user2761203, it works, many thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what the other answers are getting at.  Your `Html.ActionLink` is fine.  In your controller you have

```
AspNetUser user = db.AspNetUsers.Find(u);
if (user == null)
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
```

put a breakpoint and check if `user == null` is true. That's most likely your issue.